# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email, password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model, mass-assignment

I know that you should use "attr_accessible" to allow mass-assign protection, and that's actually what I do in my user model. How come it still complains?

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email, password
```

**user controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(2)
  end

  def login
    @user = Project.new(params[:user])
    ...
  end

end
```

**user model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :ticket

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password
end
```

**the view, _navigation.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => login_users_path, :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email%>
    <%= f.text_field(:email, :size => 30, :class => 'login_field', :placeholder => 'Användarnamn')%>
    <%= f.label :password%>
    <%= f.text_field(:password, :size => 30, :class => 'login_field', :placeholder => 'Lösenord')%>

    <%= f.submit "Logga in", :class => 'login_submit btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**from config/routes.rb:**

```
resources :users do
  post :login, on: :collection, as: :login
end
```

Because I'm using the collection above it should (as far as I understand) be the correct control / model (user) that I'm using?

Comment: cant find anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Are you aware of the `@user = Project.new(params[:user])` in your login method? Looks like the wrong model to me.

Comment: @reto: No, it's done native. :/

Comment: @holyredbeard Benedikt found the problem :D... stuff like that happnes ;D

Comment: @BenediktDeicke: I've created a collection route that uses the user controller for this, so it should be correct.

Comment: @holyredbeard. shouldnt it say `User.new(params[:user])`:)

Comment: AHH! sorry! I'm blind :D

Comment: Have you restarted your server? not sure if its mandatory though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be `User` not `Project`

```
   def login
     @user = User.new(params[:user])
     ...
   end
```

Comment: Of course. I think it's time for a break ;-) Thanks for finding this trivial problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should also change your index action to:

```
def index
  @users = Users.all
end
```

And show action to:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```